# html и css тег <button> его id

Tags: html, css

У меня проблема я привязываю тегу button id а потом пишу это id в css и у меня этот айди просто не видит  я пишу:

```
<button id="a1">
    <font size="3.5" color="Black" face="Arial"> текст </font>
</button>
```

А потом пишу в CSS

```css
.a1:hover {
  background: #dcdcdc linear-gradient(#fff, #dcdcdc);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #aaa inset, 0 1px 1px #aaa;
}
```

В итоге у меня ничего не получается 
что делать?

Comment: Потому что #a1:hover{...}

Comment: .smth это селектор класса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы обращаетесь к id то надо указывать не `.name{}` а `#name{}`